# Integrating $\iint \hat{n} \, dS $ over a closed surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

One of the exercises in the book [Div, Grad, Curl, and All That](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393925161) is to show that $$ \iint_S \hat{n} \hspace{1mm} dS = 0$$ for every closed surface $S$, using the divergence theorem.

I know the theorem, namely that $$\iint_S {F \cdot \hat{n}} \hspace{1mm} dS = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot F \hspace{1mm} dV,$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed in this case. What confuses me is the fact that I'm not integrating a scalar function anymore but a vector function... And I have no idea what should I do with the right side of the equation in this case...

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: what is $\nabla \cdot \vec{k}$ when $\vec{k}$ is a constant vector?

Comment: Doesn't it matter that $\hat{n}$ isn't a constant vector but a vector function (unit normal vector) ?

Comment: Maybe I should ask what is $\nabla \cdot F$ when $F$ is a constant vector.

Comment: It sure is $0$. So, if $F(x,y,z)=constant$, we can write $F \cdot \hat{n}$ under the integral instead of $\hat{n}$ ?

If yes, why are we formally allowed to do this?

Comment: @SchlomoSteinbergerstein: the surface integral of the vector field is performed componentwise. What is the expression for the $x$ component of $\hat n$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this problem ill-defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025691/is-this-problem-ill-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\vec{k}$ be the vector $\displaystyle \iint_S \hat{n}\,dS$, we have:

$$|\vec{k}|^2 = \vec{k} \cdot \left( \iint_S \hat{n}\,dS\right)
= \iint_S \vec{k} \cdot \hat{n}\,dS = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot \vec{k}\,dV = \iiint_{V} 0\,dV = 0\\
\implies \iint_S \hat{n} dS = \vec{k} = \vec{0}
$$

Comment: Excellent and clear, thank you!! :D